# Unable to get Entity Framework 5.0 to create database -> Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I think I read everything on SO about this today but nothing seems to work. I am using Entity Framework 5.0 with an MVC4 project.

I have an existing MVC4 project where I had some problems with the database (on SQL Server 2008 Express) which wasn't recreated even if I had my DataContextInitializer inherits from DropCreateDatabaseAlways.

So I decided to delete the database manually from SQL Server Management Studio.

When I restarted my app, I noticed that the database is never created nor initialized. The connectionString is good however.

In the Global.asax.cs in the Application_Start() I tried to call these different functions:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());

DataContext db = new DataContext();

db.Database.Initialize(true);

db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

This last line of code (CreateIfNotExists) throws an exception with "**Sequence contains no matching element**" and the database is never created. It is the same whatever I call (db.Database.Delete() / db.Database.Initialize(true)).. everything gives the same exception/error.

I am sure of my connectionstring as it was working well previously.

I tried to change the database name in my connection string to try to create a new database with a different name but the problem persists.

I tried to restart Visual Studio, IIS, SQL Server.. There is no way to create this database, I always get this "Sequence contains no matching element" no matter what I do.

It seems like the fact that I deleted the database via an external tool, EF still believes the database exists and doesn't recreate it.. Is there a cache somewhere ? I also closed all data connexion from the Server Explorer.

Any idea ?

Here is my DbContext:

```
   public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        { 
        }
```

And the initializer:

```
public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
         // Some init here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing your connection string properly?

Comment: Yes I think so:

<add name="Contoso.Manager.DataContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

Comment: Is your `DataContext` in namespace `Contoso.Manager`?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, yes I checked the name space and they're good.

Comment: Comment-out all your code in the Seed() method and rerun your application using only this in the startup `Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());`

Comment: What if you do not inherit from the initializer but just use the builtin one (so that there is no empty Seed method)? Also, post your model classes. What if you omit one of your db contexts?

Comment: I used the default initializer like this :
`Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());`

And I left only a few classes in my DbContext. The database is still not created...

What I don't understand is this error **"Sequence contains no matching element"**. Is EF not supposed to give some other error when it actually can't create the database or the database is not present ? It seems unreal that I get this type of error with no DB..

Comment: OK I made some progress, it seems that in my Company class, this line prevents the database to be created `public ICollection<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }` BillingDetail is an abstract class with 2 other classes that inherits it. I use the TPT as described here : http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx When I comment this line of code, the base gets created. If I uncomment it, the database doesn't get created anymore. Any idea ?

Comment: OK.. I found what was wrong, I had a TimeZone property in my BillingDetail class and that was preventing the database from being created...

Comment: @Flo, how did you find this. I think I am having the same problem.